# Fetch Foursquare Venues API

Tags: jquery, json, api, foursquare

im hardly trying to make an app but i need to fetch the venues from foursquare, im courrently using this code but its weird that im gettin nothing.

```
<script>
var latLong = '17.548065, -99.500868';
var url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?ll=40.7,-74&radius=500&client_id=XXXX&client_secret=XXXX&v=20120731';
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
console.log(json);
$("#results").html(json.response.groups.venue.name);
 });
</script>
```

Plus if you can help me to do the same thing with Google Places API i'll very thankful.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/?hl=es

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JSONP` instead.

Try append `?callback=?` to the `url`.

```
var url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?ll=40.7,-74&radius=500&client_id=XXXX&client_secret=XXXX&v=20120731?callback=?';
```

Comment: No working buddy, the chrome developer console now show "Unespected token"